# Triple dots animation while program is loading in terminal

Tags: python

is there a way to achieve an effect like this in Python?

[image]

I mean the flashing dots, not that green square (couldn't find a better gif).

I want to display these dots while program is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a complete solution that works in terminal

```py
from time import sleep

def printd(text, delay=.5):
    print(end=text)
    n_dots = 0

    while True:
        if n_dots == 3:
            print(end='\b\b\b', flush=True)
            print(end='   ',    flush=True)
            print(end='\b\b\b', flush=True)
            n_dots = 0
        else:
            print(end='.', flush=True)
            n_dots += 1
        sleep(delay)
```

`flush=True` forces immediate print (vs buffering)

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to print again to the same line, a simple way to do this is by not using print , but using stdout, this is what you need to do

```
import sys

sys.stdout.write('Loading.')
sys.stdout.write('\r')
sys.stdout.flush()

sys.stdout.write('Loading..')
sys.stdout.write('\r')
sys.stdout.flush()

sys.stdout.write('Loading...')
sys.stdout.write('\r')
sys.stdout.flush()
```

writing \r takes you to the start of the line, flush clears it and you rewrite over it, simple :)

Update what i like to do is, write my own convenience function as such

```
def print_(text_to_print):
    sys.stdout.write('\r')
    sys.stdout.flush()
    sys.stdout.write(text_to_print)
```

and instead of `print` call `print_`